# Push value to Array if key does not exist Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

Given mongoose schema

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    members: [
        {
            name: String,
            username: String
        }
    ]
});
```

From my code I want to push object to `members` but only if there is no given username in array yet. How can I do it with mongoose?

Comment: you can find by query like db.collection.find({'member.username':username}) if the collection is empty then push object into the member array

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could check for the username in the condition part of the update query:

```
var conditions = {
    _id: id,
    'members.username': { $ne: 'something' }
};

var update = {
    $addToSet: { members: { name: 'something', username: 'something' } }
}

SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, function(err, doc) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've run into the same problem. I would like to point out that if you want to return an error message if a member with the `username` already exists you should check `doc === null` on the object returned by `findOneAndUpdate` .