# Check if a key in array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I try to check if a value is in array's objects. After that I push the object is the value is not in the array. How can I do this ?

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
let userId = req.user.id
let dataPushSave = req.body.idSave
let dataPushSaveObj = {idSave: dataPushSave}

User.findById(userId, (err, user) => {
    if (user.favorites.idSave !== dataPushSave) {
        user.favorites.push(dataPushSaveObj)
        user.save()
    }
})
```

My mongoose model:

```
    const User = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    favorites: [{
        _id: Object,
        idSave: String
    }]
});
```

Comment: [like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26330406/9124424)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const User = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    favorites: [{
        _id: Object,
        idSave: String
    }]
});
```

From the above schema, remove _id: Object from favorites.
I would recommend below schema

```
const User = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    favorites: {
        type: [new Schema({
        idSave: { type: String },
      }, { _id: false })]
    }
});
```

Then use $addToSet operator to make sure there are no duplicates in the favorites array.

```
let user;
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  userId, 
  { $addToSet: {  favorites: dataPushSaveObj } }, 
  { new: true }, // this option will make sure you get the new updated docc
  (err, doc) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    user = doc;
  }
);
```

Comment: I have a `Tried to set nested object field `favorites` to array `[object Object]` and strict mode is set to throw.` with your solution